# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELResolver while running struts junit

Tags: struts2

I am writing junits for struts action class and using  org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase, while running the test cases I am getting below exception.

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELResolver
at org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesInitializer.createContainerFactory(StrutsTilesInitializer.java:58)
at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.createContainer(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:123)
at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.initialize(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:70)
at org.apache.tiles.web.startup.AbstractTilesListener.contextInitialized(AbstractTilesListener.java:62)
at com.dmainc.agora.action.test.SetupStrutsTestCase.setUp(SetupStrutsTestCase.java:261)
```

so I added el-api.jar in the run config , then again ran the test, but started getting another exception i.e

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getJspApplicationContext(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext;
at org.apache.tiles.el.JspExpressionFactoryFactory.getExpressionFactory(JspExpressionFactoryFactory.java:61)
at org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesContainerFactory.createELEvaluator(StrutsTilesContainerFactory.java:251)
at org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesContainerFactory.createAttributeEvaluatorFactory(StrutsTilesContainerFactory.java:198)
at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createContainer(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:106)
at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.createContainer(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:124)
at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.initialize(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:70)
at org.apache.tiles.web.startup.AbstractTilesListener.contextInitialized(AbstractTilesListener.java:62)
```

I guess this is happening due to some jar/jar version has conflict, but could not figure out why?
Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need to execute result in your tests? If not then you can skip it.

Comment: I am just capturing the result to get the status/errors.

Comment: Status from action method? You don't need execute result for that - skip it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
Inner of the apache-tomcat-x.x.xx\lib folder
el-api.jar file set classpath environment variable.

Solution 2:
copy apache-tomcat-x.x.xx\lib\el-api.jar file in to jreX.X.X_XXX\lib\ext\ folder.

because it is used to preload tomcat server start

Run again your test case.